# Python/Pandas - Mask not returning values back to column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask

First post to stack, and I am sure there is an obvious answer. Forgive my transgressions.

Anyways, my problem is like this:

I have database with 2 columns. I want to change the value of one column (make it negative), if the value of the other column meets a certain value. Basically, if column 2 (positive_p) is '1', then column 1 (response) should flip to negative (in the same row).

I have tried nearly every method (map, apply, lambda, iloc, and now mask), and I keep getting the same result no matter what. The correct values are being selected in column 1, but they are returned as blank instead of being negative. I have included the mask in my code as it seems the most elegant solution. I feel as if I'm missing something obvious here, but I can't seem to pick it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
combo5['response'].mask(combo5['positive_p'] == 0, -1*combo5['response'], inplace=True)

print(combo5)
```

Won't let me embed yet, but here is the output showing missing column values.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G150l.jpg)

Comment: Can you include the output as text?

Comment: It is a large dataframe (2032 x 15). If the image link is not working/not enough, let me know what you would like to see as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a boolean index.

```py
ix = combo5['positive_p'] == 1
combo5.loc[ix, 'response'] *= -1
```

Comment: This produces a similar result... the correct values to replace are selected, but are replaced with blanks like with my attempt with map. My best guess, is that its deleting the values in the orignal column, but applying them to a copy? Can I assume loc will try to replace original dataframe values? Still unsure of whats going on

Comment: I have accepted this answer since its 'what you would do'. The issue was my column was 'object' instead of 'int' type so it was passing the argument and returning empty values. Nice reminder to check your dtypes first!